# dask dataframe apply meta

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm wanting to do a frequency count on a single column of a `dask` dataframe. The code works, but I get an `warning` complaining that `meta` is not defined. If I try to define `meta` I get an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`. For this particular use case it doesn't look like I need to define `meta` but I'd like to know how to do that for future reference.

Dummy dataframe and the column frequencies

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Sam', 'Alex', 'David', 'Sarah', 'Alice', 'Sam', 'Anna'],
                   ['Sam', 'David', 'David', 'Alice', 'Sam', 'Alice', 'Sam'],
                   [12, 10, 15, 23, 18, 20, 26]],
                  index=['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C']).T
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df)
```

---

```
In [39]: dask_df.head()
Out[39]: 
  Column A Column B Column C
0      Sam      Sam       12
1     Alex    David       10
2    David    David       15
3    Sarah    Alice       23
4    Alice      Sam       18
```

---

```
(dask_df.groupby('Column B')
        .apply(lambda group: len(group))
       ).compute()

UserWarning: `meta` is not specified, inferred from partial data. Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.
  Before: .apply(func)
  After:  .apply(func, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}) for dataframe result
  or:     .apply(func, meta=('x', 'f8'))            for series result
  warnings.warn(msg)
Out[60]: 
Column B
Alice    2
David    2
Sam      3
dtype: int64
```

---

Trying to define `meta` produces `AttributeError`

```
 (dask_df.groupby('Column B')
         .apply(lambda d: len(d), meta={'Column B': 'int'})).compute()
```

same for this

```
 (dask_df.groupby('Column B')
         .apply(lambda d: len(d), meta=pd.DataFrame({'Column B': 'int'}))).compute()
```

same if I try having the `dtype` be `int` instead of `"int"` or for that matter `'f8'` or `np.float64` so it doesn't seem like it's the `dtype` that is causing the problem.

The documentation on `meta` seems to imply that I should be doing exactly what I'm trying to do (http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#metadata).

What is `meta`? and how am I supposed to define it?

Using `python 3.6` `dask 0.14.3` and `pandas 0.20.2`

Comment: Hmm, not sure why that would fail.  Does this work `meta=('Column B', 'int')` ?

Comment: Not to answer your question, but how about `dask_df.groupby('Column B').count().compute()`? That gets the number of valid values in each column, not the length. `dask_df['Column B'].value_counts().compute()` is a more exact translation.
The error I believe is because the output has Column B as the *index* not the column name.

Comment: both of those seem to do the right thing, no idea which one is the most effective

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`meta` is the prescription of the names/types of the output from the computation. This is required because `apply()` is flexible enough that it can produce just about anything from a dataframe. As you can see, if you don't provide a `meta`, then dask actually computes part of the data, to see what the types should be - which is fine, but you should know it is happening. 
You can avoid this pre-computation (which can be expensive) and be more explicit when you know what the output should look like, by providing a zero-row version of the output (dataframe or series), or just the types.

The output of your computation is actually a series, so the following is the simplest that works

```
(dask_df.groupby('Column B')
     .apply(len, meta=('int'))).compute()
```

but more accurate would be

```
(dask_df.groupby('Column B')
     .apply(len, meta=pd.Series(dtype='int', name='Column B')))
```

Comment: is there any performance boost to including the full pd.Series meta?

Comment: No, but it's more explicit, and in some cases allows you finer control, e.g., over the name and type of the index.